# jQuery UI layout plug-in OVERFLOW setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-layout

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jxTUw/14/) is provided for better illustration. 
In this case I am using two plugins: [jQuery UI layout plugin](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/index.cfm) & [Trent datetime picker plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

The pop-up datetime picker will be blocked by the west pane resize bar. If I set option `west__showOverflowOnHover: true`, the scroll bar won't work. I am follow the overflow setting instruction [**here**](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/documentation.cfm#Drop-Downs), but still not get it through yet.

Or maybe there is a conflict between these two plugins?

Comment: The problem is the bar that divides in two the screen, which is overlapping the datepicker?

Comment: yes, that's my problem. I want the date picker will be on the upper layer. Let me know if you still not quite sure. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `z-index`, in this file `jquery-ui.css` search for the class `.ui-datepicker` and add the property like this:

```
.ui-datepicker {
   width: 17em;
   padding: .2em .2em 0;
   z-index: 100 !important;
}
```

For the moment I overwrite the class, [you can check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/luissanchezm86/jxTUw/15/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem solved! I was waiting the count down to accept your answer.. very quick answer, lol